# Hide keyboard for date-picker in ipod and mobiles for angularJs

Tags: angularjs, mobile, datepicker, ipod

I included a date column in a form

```
<input ng-model="model.value" data-bs-datepicker="" type="text" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" />
```

And when I click on the input box either in mobile or ipod it is showing both keyboard and custom date picker, I tried `readonly="true" and element.blur();` both are not working.

I am using Eonasdan date picker and there is a issue of

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/494

Is there a way to solve this problem?